# Calling Android's cpp code from your app

Tags: android, bluetooth, java-native-interface, hid

I want to call functions provided in `com_android_bluetooth_hid.cpp` in android source from my own app. Target Android versions are >=4.4 and <=5.x. I understand JNI, and can compile my own code and call from my own app.

Would it be possible to call android's library from my app? How

Also, to call functions in that specific cpp file, are BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions sufficient or something else (other permission, or root) would be required?

Comment: I need to receive (vendor-specific) hid reports from my device. Currently android system is eating all reports.
Looking through the code, I find that `get_report_cb` in `sBluetoothHidCallbacks` is left NULL in this code. Also `BluetoothInputDevice` class doesn't have any callback interface to receive these reports. So I want to put my own callback function in there, and interact with this code directly in my app, bypassing Android's java stack if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to call Android's CPP code is, generally, copying the relevant pieces to your repository and building as part of your app. Following this approach, your app will only call the public APIs - either Java or C/C++.

But this may not be relevant in cases when this code must run with special permissions, as system service, like mediaserver or Bluetooth stack.

I am afraid that the code you wish to run belongs to this second category, therefore none of the available tricks will not help.

On the other hand, a custom ROM may be a solution you are looking for. It may happen that you don't need to forge a full system. It may be enough to use a rooted device and replace the bluetooth service with your custom one.

I would still advise you to provide the missing callbacks for the service, instead of calling the functions directly from your app: you better not mix contexts between a user-space app and system service.

Comment: `I would still advise you to provide the missing callbacks for the service`
By this did you mean, provide callbacks somehow in vanilla system, or in a replaced bluetooth service through custom rom/rooting? Thanks

Comment: Provide callbacks through custom ROM/rooting

Comment: I was hoping  that there would be some way to accomplish this without root permission/custom rom, so thought best to ask seniors. Thanks for your reply.